# Parallel::ForkManager doesn't work with Perl 5.36

Tags: perl, parallel-processing

I have a script that runs well with Perl < 5.36:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use feature 'say';
use autodie ':all';
use Parallel::ForkManager;

sub execute {
    my $command = shift;
    print "Executing Command: $command\n";
    if (system($command) != 0) {
        my $fail_filename = "$0.fail";
        print "$command failed.\n";
        die;
    }
}

sub run_parallel {
    my $cmd = shift;
    my $manager = new Parallel::ForkManager(2);
    foreach my $command (@{ $cmd }) {
        $manager->start and next;
        execute( $command );
        $manager->finish;
    }
    $manager->wait_all_children;#necessary after all lists
}

my @commands = ('echo "a"','echo "b"','echo "c"','which ls','which rm');
run_parallel(\@commands);
```

but when I make minor changes with the above to 5.36:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.036;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use autodie ':all';
use Parallel::ForkManager;

sub execute {
    my $command = shift;
    print "Executing Command: $command\n";
    if (system($command) != 0) {
        my $fail_filename = "$0.fail";
        print "$command failed.\n";
        die;
    }
}

sub run_parallel {
    my $cmd = shift;
    my $manager = new Parallel::ForkManager(2);
    foreach my $command (@{ $cmd }) {
        $manager->start and next;
        execute( $command );
        $manager->finish;
    }
    $manager->wait_all_children;#necessary after all lists
}

my @commands = ('echo "a"','echo "b"','echo "c"','which ls','which rm');
run_parallel(\@commands);
```

I get an error:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at debug.pl line 20, near "new Parallel::ForkManager"
```

All I switched was `use 5.036`

Is `Parallel::ForkManager` incompatible with perl 5.36 or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `Parallel::ForkManager->new(2)`

Comment: See https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2020/06/turn-off-indirect-object-notation/ and https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj#Indirect-Object-Syntax

Comment: @zdim The 5.36 feature bundle does indeed disable indirect method syntax.

Comment: @Shawn thank you your solution fixed the problem. If you write an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Tip: I'd use `exec` instead of `system`. No need for the extra process. For that matter, I'd use the multi-arg version of `system`/`exec` to avoid the shell too. Doing both of those things will reduce the number of processes created by 10 in your example!  (Well, in theory. In practice, Perl already avoids spawning some of the shells, so it's really only 8.)

Comment: Tip: Error messages should be printed to STDERR (using `warn`, `print STDERR ...`, `say STDERR ...`, etc), not STDOUT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perl v5.36 with `use v5.36` turns off indirect object notation, where the method comes before the invocant:

```
my $p = new Some::Module;     # indirect object notation
my $p = Some::Module->new();  # what you should do
```

If this is inconvenient for you in the short term, you can `require` the minimum version so you still get the things turned off by `use v5.36`:

```
require v5.36;
```

If you don't actually use v5.36 features, also consider requiring the minimum version that your code actually needs. In your snippet, I don't immediately see any minimum version requirement (other than just Perl 5).

Answer (score 4):

Loading the 5.36 feature bundle (which you do through `use 5.036;`) [disables](https://perldoc.perl.org/feature#The-%27indirect%27-feature) the indirect method call syntax as if you had done `no feature qw( indirect );`.

This is a method call using the indirect syntax:

```perl
METHODNAME INVOCANT ARGS
```

Either re-enable the feature or use the "direct" syntax:

```perl
INVOCANT->METHODNAME( ARGS )
```

In your case,

```perl
my $manager = Parallel::ForkManager->new( 2 );
```